# Multipartfile charset=UTF-8 is not supported spring boot api rest

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The code was working normally and I've tried in every way to solve it and I couldn't, it may be that after I transformed the MultipartFile into an array this happened

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("products")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<ShowProductsDTO> registerProduct(
            @RequestBody @Valid ProductDTO dto,
            @RequestParam(name = "files", required = true) MultipartFile[] files, 
            UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder) {
        ShowProductsDTO showProductsDTO = null;
        try {
            showProductsDTO = productService.save(dto, files);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        var uri = uriBuilder.path("/products/{id}").buildAndExpand(showProductsDTO.id()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(showProductsDTO);

    }
```

DTO

```java
public record ProductDTO(
    @NotBlank
    String name,
    @NotBlank
    String description,
    @NotNull
    @NumberFormat
    BigDecimal price,
    @NumberFormat
    @NotNull
    Integer quantity,
    @NotNull
    Boolean active,
    @NotNull
    Long sub_category_id
    ) {

}
```

Error console

> Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException:
> Content-Type
> 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------816548045966415708649211;charset=UTF-8'
> is not supported]

Postman body > raw > json

```json
{
    "name": "Nome do produto",
    "description": "descricao do produto",
    "price": "2500.00",
    "quantity": "2",
    "active": "true",
    "sub_category_id": "1"
}
```

Postman > body > form-data

```
KEY "files", TYPE file, VALUE uma imagem minha em png
```

Error postman

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2023-01-11T06:15:43.455+00:00",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------056640214920648036756520;charset=UTF-8' is not supported.",
    "path": "/products"
}
```

Product entity

```
@Table(name = "products")
@Entity(name = "Product")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 100, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String description;
    @Column(length = 8, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "NUMERIC(8,2)")
    private BigDecimal price;
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT")
    private Integer quantity;
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN")
    private Boolean active;

    @CollectionTable(name = "products_files", 
            joinColumns = 
            @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<String> productFiles;

    @JoinColumn(name = "sub_category_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private SubCategory subCategory;
```

how do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Change your attribute to `@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

and call your api using `Postman body > raw > json`.


The thing is, `Content-Type: form-data` handles file requests.

Comment: I just edited the post and put the product entity, it's not your fault because it wasn't clear but I need to receive photo and video files because every product in the store will have a photo or video